# Mean Value Theorem to prove inequality

Tags: calculus

Prove that: $\frac{x}{x^2+1}<\arctan x< x$ for (x > 0)

Not sure how to do this. I know that if $f(x)=\arctan x$ then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ but then what? How do I go about proving this. Please explain what to do next and why this works.

Answer (score 4):

Applying the mean value theorem for the $\arctan$ function on the interval $[0,x]$ : there's $c \in(0,x)$ such that
$$\arctan x= \frac{x}{1+c^2}$$
and since $0<c<x$ then we get
$$\frac{x}{1+x^2}<\frac{x}{1+c^2}< x$$